# git merge "Already up to date" with cross-over merge

Tags: git, git-branch, git-merge

I have two development paths that branched in the past. I want to keep both branches and tried to merge each into the other for both branches. I was able to merge the second path into the first one, solve some merge conflicts but I am unable to merge the first into the second, because git complains about being already up-to-date.

Here are some illustrations. A and B are the branches, the numbers indicate individual commits. The situation before my first merge was:

```
            /- B1 <-- B2
A1 <-- A2 <--  A3 <-- A4 <-- A5
```

Then I checkout out branch A (commit A5) and merge B into it after solving some conflicts:

```
git checkout A
git merge B
# Solve conflicts here
git commit
```

Then my situation is as follows:

```
            /- B1 <-- B2 <-------\
A1 <-- A2 <--  A3 <-- A4 <-- A5 <-- A6
```

Now, I want to merge A into B in order to get the following:

```
            /- B1 <-- B2 <-------\    /-- B3
A1 <-- A2 <--  A3 <-- A4 <-- A5 <-- A6
```

So I did

```
git checkout B   # Now, I am back at B2
git merge A
```

and I get the "Already-up-to date warning". What is wrong?

Comment: Why not branching out from A6? Both your B and your A code are already there.

Comment: Also, what does `git diff B..A` return?

Comment: I see my last figure is misleading. Actually, I do not want a new commit B3 but the HEAD pointer of branch B should point to the same commit as A already does (i.e. point to A6). Of course I could delete branch B and restart branch B from A6 again. @Railside: I already though of that but I hoped there would be a cleaner approach. All that is needed is a fast-forward of B to A6, because A6 is a direct descendant of B. Surprisingly, `git checkout B; git merge --ff A` did the trick. But I do not know, why the `--ff` option is explicitly required, I though git would figure out this by itself.

Comment: This is indeed odd; `git merge --ff A` is exactly the same as `git merge A`, unless you have `merge.ff` set to false. Even if you _did_ have it set to false, the result of `git merge A` would be a normal (non-ff) merge commit, not an "Already up to date" message. FWIW, I tried reproducing your problem on my machine and got the expected behavior (a ff merge).